# how to save an image of tif format by converting into jpg during fileupload?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is the code I have used to upload a file and save it in a folder, but the problem is with `.tif` images, as browsers does not support them.
Because of this, I want to convert the image to `.jpg` before saving to folder.

This is my current code:

```
 Try
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        Dim hfc As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
        Dim PathName As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To hfc.Count - 1
            Dim hpf As HttpPostedFile = hfc(i)

            If hpf.ContentLength > 0 Then

                  PathName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)
                Dim QuoteNumber As String = objQuoteParent.QuoteTabImage.ToList().Item(i).QuoteNumber
                Dim FName As String = QuoteNumber + "_QOT_" + (i.ToString()) + PathName
                Dim FileName As String = "~/UploadedImages/" + FName

               'what should i use before saving to convert a tif file to jpg then save?

                hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages\") & FName)

            End If
        Next
    Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception

        Throw
    End Try
```

before saving the file into folder I want to check if any `.tif` is uploaded if yes then first convert it to `jpg` then save it into the folder.

Comment: Your question uses English words, but does not appear to convey a complete thought.  Try again please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
I used the below code:

```
   My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(filepath, Name + ".jpg")
```

This code is able to convert .tif to jpg but after converting i am unable to display the image file.

Answer (score 1):

Found This Function on Google [TIFF image <--> JPEG image converter](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VBTiffImageConverter-f8fdfd7f)

```
Public Shared Function ConvertTiffToJpeg(fileName As String) As String()
    Using imageFile As Image = Image.FromFile(fileName)
        Dim frameDimensions As New FrameDimension(imageFile.FrameDimensionsList(0))

        ' Gets the number of pages from the tiff image (if multi-page)
        Dim frameNum As Integer = imageFile.GetFrameCount(frameDimensions)
        Dim jpegPaths As String() = New String(frameNum) {}

        Dim frame As Integer = 0
        While frame < frameNum
            ' Selects one frame at a time and save as jpeg.
            imageFile.SelectActiveFrame(frameDimensions, frame)
            Using bmp As New Bitmap(imageFile)
                jpegPaths(frame) = [String].Format("{0}\{1}{2}.jpeg",
                                   Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName),
                                   Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), frame)
                bmp.Save(jpegPaths(frame), ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            End Using
            System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(frame), frame - 1)
        End While

        Return jpegPaths
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but can u give any suggestion which i can use in my code mentioned above @al-3sli

Comment: use it after your condition `If hpf.ContentLength > 0 Then` Create a condition to check if it `tif` or not , if `tif` then call the function like this  `ConvertTiffToJpeg(FileName)`

Comment: try it and tell me if you need more help.

Comment: can anyone help me,I am getting error while using the above conversion function that "parameter is not valid"